# A way to search location without Map being visible?

Tags: swift, search, mapkit, uisearchbar

I'm new to iOS developing, any help or resources are appreciated!

Is there a way to search for a city, town, state or country using a search bar without having the map visible? I basically want to have the customer type in any location, select it and then view search results in that location that the client added on their controller/log in. I've already created the log in/sign up, eventually I want to integrate Stripe for each search result.

I've tried looking for tutorials online, but only seem to find tutorials based off of having the actual Map visible and inputting regular text.

Comment: Why not follow one of those tutorials, but ignore the code tying it to a map?

Comment: Will that work? Do I still 'import MapKit', etc? I guess that's where I'm getting confused.

Comment: You only need to import mapkit if you're dealing with locations, maps, or annotations. If you only want the search functionality, you do not need mapkit

Comment: I want to be able to search for a location though. For example, in the search bar I start typing "new york city"- it automatically comes up as an option to click on "New York City, New York" or something similar. Or for example I type in, "Panama" and in the search results are the options, "Panama City, Panama" or "Panama City, Florida". I just don't want the Map to be visible in my app..

Comment: You can integrate location autocompletion without having a map as they are two separate protocols. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can initialize a uisearchbar without tying it to a map. You then make your class a delegate and tell it how to handle searches. The following is in Swift 2

First, make your class a delegate:

```
class yourClass: UISearchBarDelegate
```

Initialize the controller

```
var searchController: UISearchController!
searchController = UISearchController(nil) // nil means you want to show the results on the same page as the search
```

Then, in whatever action will present the search:

```
self.presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now you tell it how to handle a search using one or more of these methods:

```
func searchBar(UISearchBar, textDidChange: String) //the user changed the search text
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(UISearchBar) // user stopped changing search text
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) // user clicked "Search"
```

According to the docs:

> At a minimum, the delegate needs to perform the actual search when text is entered in the text field.

So using any of those methods should meet the minimum requirement

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/) for the full docs

Comment: Please don't post Link-Only answers. You can point out the solution and then add references

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I updated the answer to not be garbage